# Internationalization in Jhipster

Tags: jhipster

I am new to Jhipster and am using version 4.2.0

I am using two languages enabled on project start up ( en and hi )

I added new links to my nav and updated the translation table under

"webapp/i18n/en/global.json" with the keys as below :

```
{
"global": {
       "menu":{
       "candidate": {
            "dashboard" : "Dashboard",
            "profile" : "Profile",
            }
       }
      }
}
```

I see under the project I have corresponding translation table for hi

"webapp/i18n/hi/global.json"

How do we update this table for every new link we create ?

Does jhiTranslate not work on the primary language and create the translation on the fly ?

In html when I use the key with hi as selected language

```
<span jhitranslate="global.menu.candidate.dashboard">Dashboard</span>
```

I get translation-not-found error.

Comment: As far as I can tell the translations are done manually. If you have to put new entries to lets say i18n/en/global.json you have to put on i18n/hi/global.json also. As an alternative you can search for a JSON translation editor software to make the task easier